# Minimum and maximum dates for datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery for making a datepicker and I am facing the following problem with it:-

1. I want to show a minimum date of 1970  in the drop down menu of the calender which I am not able to do.
2. I also want to show a maximum year of (current year - 20) in the same drop down.

How can these things be done?

Also, I want to monitor a text box using jQuery for keystrokes. When the third character is entered in the text box, I want to make an Ajax call to get all the fields from a db which matches those 3 starting characters and show them in a suggestion box.

Can anyone please tell me how these problems can be resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have a look at the jquery ui docs - you'll find "yearRange" under options

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

For the second question, also jquery ui:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: new Date(1970,1, 1), maxDate: "-20Y" });
    });
```

See

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/min-max.html

Comment: That will work - but since he explictely asks about years, the yearRange options seems more fitting